# Robot Framework-"Undefined Keyword" (VSC not reloaded as I CTRL + S)

Tags: visual-studio-code, robotframework

When i add a new keyword that's connected to my PO file in the Visual Studio Code, and I already have Resources code entered for previous keywords, when i add a new one, there is an error "Undefined Keyword", and then, if i enter ANOTHER same "Resources ./PO/Something.robot, so basically exactly the same as the one above it, the error disappears. Of course, also, if I save it with an error, I close VSC, and open it again, error is gone-So the bottom line, my VSC does not read the new state. Why is that?

Tried nothing special except the few things anyone else would try

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding details. Since you are having your tests in one folder and resources in another, You need to make changes as below:

```
Resource  ../PO/<file>.robot
```

Comment: https://prnt.sc/VKvK_yZLvuDw

Comment: Updated my answer, please check and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no https://prnt.sc/bC5SSCVwquJW

I retrieve those resources in the right way, that part is good, the issue appears if I make a change, then that change is not read in the other folder, then I add a resource THAT ALREADY exists (+1), and just then the VSC reads it. The issue is about loading changes.

Comment: ah ok, retry loading project and reinstalling selenium/robot libs. that just an alternative.